# thick left border on cardView android studio

Tags: android

This is the first time for me to create an mobile apps. Im using android studio for develop it. I want to ask how to create a **thick left border in cardView?** im confused. I find out in this forum and there are no answers

Can somebody help me?

I want to create a card like this
[card examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JVqW.png)

But what i code just like this
[what i just created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lOst.png)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    style="@style/ListStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.219">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The style too if needed

```
<style name="ListStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">2dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">2dp</item>
    <item name="contentPaddingBottom">24dp</item>
    <item name="contentPaddingTop">24dp</item>
    <item name="contentPaddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="contentPaddingRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/putih</item>
</style>
```

Thanks for helping me:)

Comment: please show your code of cardview

Comment: @SopheakSok im forgot that, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Use this code :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/RippleStyleBlack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/seeall_lead_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:elevation="10dp"
          >

            <View
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#D64D4D">

            </View>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_image"

                    />


                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/lead_NameNew"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
                    android:text="Add List"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is work! but can u explain me how it works? i just copied ur code and its working, but idk why it can. Thanks:)